# cookie not working in popup on colorbox load

Tags: javascript, cookies, popup, colorbox

I'm trying to get this simple cookie working in my simple colorbox but it isn't.
Could someone point me in the right direction because I'm not that handy with javascript. Thx

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function () {

setTimeout(function() {
$.fn.colorbox({href:"{{ 'missroberta-international.jpg' | url_asset }}", open:true});  
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function () { $.fn.colorbox.close(); }, 8000);


$(function() {
    if ($.cookie('test_status') != '1')
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            alert('foo');
            jQuery.cookie('test_status', '1', { expires: 31}); 
        }, 1000);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your DOM ready functions are not properly closed. The first ins't closed at all, and the second needs `})` not just `}`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

setTimeout(function() {
$.fn.colorbox({href:"{{ 'missroberta-international.jpg' | url_asset }}", open:true});  
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function () { $.fn.colorbox.close(); }, 8000);

}); // <-- here

$(function() {
    if ($.cookie('test_status') != '1')
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            alert('foo');
            jQuery.cookie('test_status', '1', { expires: 31}); 
        }, 1000);
    }

}); // <-- here
```

Unless this code appears separately in the HTML, there is no point in using both `$(function(){ ... })` and `$(document).ready` because the former is a shortcut to the latter, so combine the code into one if possible.